# error "gatsby-transformer-cloudinary" threw an error while running the onCreateNode lifecycle

Tags: gatsby, cloudinary

I am interacting with a MongoDB backend with gatsby. There is a node which sometimes has images and sometimes doesn't so each of these nodes has a child node within it called cloudinary. I get an error from gatsby-transformer-cloudinary appearing when trying to automatically create nodes as documented here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-transformer-cloudinary in the "Use images already on Cloudinary" section.

our node structure is a bit like this:

```
artwork: {
   mediaItems: {
      cloudinary: {
         cloudinaryAssetData: true,
         ... other relevant stuff
      }
   }
   mediaItems: {
      ... this one doesn't contain a cloudinary image node
   }
```

sometimes a mediaItem would have the above node in the MongoDB structure, sometimes not. I then got the error below

```
cannot convert undefined or null to object

  53 |   const currentNode = basePath === '' ? node : get(node, basePath);
  54 | 
> 55 |   const directAssetDataPaths = Object.keys(currentNode)
     |                                       ^
  56 |     .filter(key => {
  57 |       return currentNode[key] && currentNode[key].cloudinaryAssetData === true;
  58 |     })


  TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
  
  - Function.keys
  
  - create-asset-nodes-from-data.js:55 getAssetDataPaths
    [rca-wip-2021-public]/[gatsby-transformer-cloudinary]/gatsby-node/create-asset-nodes-from-data.js:55:39
  
  - create-asset-nodes-from-data.js:72 
    [rca-wip-2021-public]/[gatsby-transformer-cloudinary]/gatsby-node/create-asset-nodes-from-data.js:72:12
  
  - _arrayMap.js:16 arrayMap
    [rca-wip-2021-public]/[gatsby-transformer-cloudinary]/[lodash]/_arrayMap.js:16:21
```

I have tried adding otherwise empty nodes in the database with cloudinaryAssetData: false wherever there isn't an image, to try to remedy this, but that hasn't worked so far. As below:
mediaItems: {
cloudinary: {
cloudinaryAssetData: false
}
}

It does seem that gatsby automatically creates null data for any empty fields/nodes, this might be the problem. If anyone has any insight into this i'd be grateful. It might be something i can solve my end by setting defaults, or modifying the data at the gatsby, or changing the way MongoDB is structured perhaps (but that's much harder to modify).

Answer (score 1):

Gatsby is able to automatically infer a GraphQL Schema from your data, and in many cases, this is really all you need. There are however situations when you either want to explicitly define the data shape or add custom functionality to the query layer by [adding nullability property to some fields](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/graphql-data-layer/schema-customization/).

Of course with this customization, you are diving into the GraphQL schema creation and maybe, it's easier to change the MongoDB structure to add some empty or dummy fields and trim them once queried if you are not comfortable customizing the schema.

Comment: thanks thats useful - i thought that might be part of a way of solving this. I agree that changing the db is easier, unfortunately, that might not be doable. I did however make a very simple patch to the plugin which 'fixes' this. commented above, perhaps not ideal!